# Rails: Refactoring restful controller specs: Why don't people do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rspec

Like most rails folks my restful controllers stick to a very consistent pattern, and any changes are rarely more than an extra line or two.

I like to test (using RSpec) fairly thoroughly, and that includes assigns, responds, redirects etc in controller tests.

The thing is, 75% of my controller specs follow the exact same pattern, and an obvious step seems to be to refactor them into a method/set of methods that I can call from each spec....either with a single (for example) 'restful_controller_specs' call, or individual 'restful_index_specs', 'restful_show_specs' etc for actions if the resource isn't completely standard.

And yet, when looking at other people's projects, from what I can see nobody else really seems to do that.

So in short, am I missing a good reason as to why not to agressively refactor restful controller specs?

Answer (score 0):

I think most rails developers have learned programming by learning rails, which is not the ideal way to learn how to program, so things like refactoring are not a concept they have learned or encountered.  Many people don't realise that files like `config/routes.rb` and `db/migrate/*` are just ruby code, and you can add loops and arrays and classes and subclasses into them as you need, just like any ruby program.

To all the rails coders out there: learn ruby! learn it *well*! It's a real programming language! Rails is made entirely of ruby.